# Slow Query in Big Database

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization

I have slow queries with a mysql request. But the request is not difficult:

```
SELECT * FROM emailarchiv WHERE typ='MAIL'  AND benutzer = '542' ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 0,50;
# User@Host: XXX[XXX] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 13245239  Schema: usr_XXX_1  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 20.919740  Lock_time: 0.000066  Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 79212
```

Ok, in the database are 79212 entrys...but 20seconds???

My System: Centos7 MariaDB 5.5, 10GB RAM, 10 CPUs

Here my my.conf:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile = 0
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user = mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
# Forced OLD_PASSWORD format is turned OFF by Plesk
#old_passwords = 1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links = 0

max_connections = 100
#port = 3306 #Port nicht aendern
key_buffer_size = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 256M
table_open_cache = 4096
sort_buffer_size = 64M
net_buffer_length = 128K
read_buffer_size = 1512K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4096K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
tmp_table_size = 1024M
key_cache_block_size = 4096
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_limit = 512M
thread_cache_size = 20
table_cache = 16384
#open_files_limit = 9212 #nicht aktivieren!! Verursacht Probleme...
#wait_timeout = 10 #nicht aktivieren !!
join_buffer_size = 32M
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1

#Aenderungen ab 23.07.2021
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size= 1024M
skip-name-resolve
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /srv/slow-query.log
long_query_time = 5

ssl-ca=/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-key.pem

[mysqld_safe]
#log-error = /var/log/mysqld.log
```

What goes here wrong?

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND Optional very helpful information includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `select version()`, `show create table emailarchiv` and `explain SELECT rest-of-your-query`; this is minimal information needed for query optimization help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself ;-)

I don't use indexes for the rows "typ" and "benutzer" that was the problem. Now the Query_time is 2 seconds

Comment: Congratulations. Will still provide suggestions from workload analysis if data is provided.